# SQL REGEXP_REPLACE() function

Tags: sql, database, replace, regexp-replace, greenplum

I have a table with names that has the values like this:

| Customer |
| --- |
| marco rossi |
| .paolo esposito |
| jimmi montana |
| **Luke skywalker |
| marinella abc |
| - ÚDRST MARK |
| -úgo srl |

What i wanted was to delete all the special characters in the beginning of the names.
I used this function REGEXP.REPLACE('[^a-zA-Z0-9]*|[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$/g',''))

And this return me almost what i wanted but delete me also the
Ú, ú
So instead of having [ ÚDRST MARK ] i have [ DRST MARK ]

What i can add in this function for not replacing the characters with accents in the beginning of the words?

Thank u so much guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `Ú` and `ú` special characters, what about adding them inside the non capturing group?

```
REGEXP.REPLACE('[^a-zA-Z0-9Úú]|[^a-zA-Z0-9Úú]$/g',''))
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: I tried now, but still the same problem, the function delete the first character with accent. Have u other ideas?

Comment: Misread the question, I thought you wanted to remove those characters too. I've updated the answer accordingly.